# Find distance between parallel lines given distance of reflected coordinates

Tags: geometry

[image]

It seems like it'd be really simple to solve but I have no idea how.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Let’s consider a single point:

A-A’ is twice the distance A-m

A’A’’ is twice the distance A’-n

Comment: AA’’=A’A’’-AA’=2A’n-2Am=2(nm+Am)-2Am=2nm